# Mounting a webDAV share for all users

Tags: mount, permissions, webdav, davfs2

I'm trying to mount a webDAV share with this fstab line:

> myserverip /media/myserver/ davfs noauto,user,rw 0 0

I have added the secret credentials to `~/.davfs2/secrets`.

Also done `sudo dpkg-reconfigure davfs2` to allow mounting by non-root users.

This all works fine if I have the following in `/etc/davfs2/davfs2.conf`:

```
dav_user        myusername         # system wide config file only
dav_group       myusername         # system wide config file only
```

But this obviously only works for one user, however if I leave it at the default:

```
dav_user        davfs2           # system wide config file only
dav_group       davfs2           # system wide config file only
```

and add my user account to the group davfs2 via

> sudo usermod -aG davfs2 myusername

which is successful as shown by the output of `groups myusername`:

```
myusername : myusername davfs2
```

However when I now try to mount the share I get the following error:

```
/sbin/mount.davfs: user myusername must be a member of group davfs2
```

So how do I get it to mount by group and why does it not recognize that I’m in the correct group.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your running login session might not be updated with the new group yet. Try just calling `groups` and see if that lists davfs2.

```
$ sudo useradd foo -M
$ groups
myuser adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
$ sudo usermod -aG foo myuser
$ groups
myuser adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
$ su -l myuser
$ groups
myuser myuser adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare foo
```

Comment: Yep, noticed my mistake just now... got myself locked out of the sudo, can probably restore that, but is there anyway I can find out what user groups I'm supposed to be part of?

Comment: also mounting works just fine after a reboot.

Comment: Maybe create new user and check the groups that he gets put in? also, sudo, of course.

Comment: Logout and login helped.

Comment: I realize I never explicitly suggested a solution:  `su -l myuser` will also update your current login session