# webDAV mount contains only `lost+found` folder

Tags: mount, 22.04, fstab, webdav

I want to mount a webDAV remote on my ubuntu 22.04 system. Precisely, this is on a private storage service and is accessible through either

*i)* my credetials at the link https://pandora.infn.it/ws-my-files/test-webDAV-mount

*ii)* a public link without passwords: https://pandora.infn.it/public/13359c

I tried following [this guide](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/mount.davfs.8.html) , taking some hints from other sources. The exact steps I did are the following:

1. Install webdav `sudo apt-get install davfs2`, ensuring to enable non-root mounts.
2. Edit `/etc/fstab` (I tested both the above links):

```
$ sudo nano /etc/fstab

# append lines:
https://pandora.infn.it/public/13359c /home/luca/pandora_public davfs ro,user,noauto 0 0
https://pandora.infn.it/ws-my-files/test-webDAV-mount /home/luca/pandora_credentials davfs ro,user,noauto 0 0
```

3. Add my user to *davfs2* group as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/498495/954348):

```
sudo usermod -aG davfs2 luca
su -l luca
```

If I check, my user correctly shows *davfs2* among its groups:

```
$ groups
luca adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare davfs2 docker
```

At this point, I should be able to run `$ mount pandora_public` or `$ mount pandora_credentials`, but in either case I am prompted for credentials and get `/sbin/mount.davfs: mounting failed; the server does not support WebDAV`.

So I also edited `/etc/davfs2/davfs2.conf` appending `ignore_dav_header 1` as suggested [here](https://help.nextcloud.com/t/the-server-does-not-support-webdav/57545/8).

Finally, if I re-try it seems both commands (`$ mount pandora_public` or `$ mount pandora_credentials`) work and indeed I have a mounted directory. However, mount points only contain a `lost+found` empty folder.

I suspect it must be something with the authentication since I get the same results even if I use deliberately wrong username and password, however I don't get any error message nor warning. Any help would be much appreciated :D

Hope to have included all relevant details, don't hesitate to ask for more info if needed!